# QNX 6.5.0 grab screen or window Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, qnx

I need to grab the screen or window in QNX 6.5.0 - 8 times per second. If use standart low-level API function **PgReadScreen()**, for resolution screen 1920x1080 (24 bit) its very slooow... When create context PdCreateDirectContext(), the driver blocks all other painting. It freezes the screen for a few seconds.

I also looked at the regions, but as I understood, they do not contain graphic data of windows?

Used Qt 5.7.1 with reduced functionality. For example, the function **grabWindow()** not implemented.

Good idea: use the widget's **render()** function, but some objects... for example: list of comboBox is widget too. I have to follow and draw it too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Window-grabbing is really simple. A top-level `QWidget` (`widget.isWindow()==true`) is backed by a `QImage` backing store. Grabbing this requires no repainting or OS API calls. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749538/1329652) has a working, mostly complete yet simple implementation of this idea. It should be portable to any platform and any widget as long as the raster backend is used.